# Examining (semi-) random structures?

Tags: soft-question, axioms

Typically, much of mathematics today is ultimately based on pretty abstract axiomatisations in first order logic (or, rarely, some other logic).

But all of those axiomatisations, whether for arithmetic (PA and all its extensions examined in reverse mathematics), set theory (ZFC, NBG and their variations), group theory, geometry (with good old Euklid and its variations), order theory etc, all result from having a preconceived idea of a mathematical structure (such as a group or sets) and then translating the ideas and concepts into formal language.

That leads to **question 1**: Are there any significant results in any area that started the other way? Has there ever been a case where someone sat down, came up with random axioms (perhaps with some bias, especially trying to avoid contradictions), thought on what models those axioms could have and what theorems would be valid?

A very mild example would be the development of non-Euklidian geometries, only that even then, most axioms were already "derived" from previously existing mathematics, or perhaps the various ZF variants being studied - but what I'm really looking for is more extreme cases with much less previously existing conceptions.

**Question 2**: Assuming some guidance by mathematical knowledge in conceiving the axioms, is there a reason to suspect that all such theories and their described structures are "useless" or "not interesting"?

**Edit to clarify and rephrase the question**, since apparently the above can be misunderstood:
What I'm really asking: most math starts from having some conception of a structure and then making it concrete in the language of mathematics.
The question I'm wanting to ask is if there are any significant results that were achieved the other way around: Inventing some rules first a priori, that is, without some previous idea of a structure, then examining the results.

Comment: You are making unwarranted assumptions about the nature and development of Mathematics, in particular about axiomatisation.

Comment: @Somos Err. How so?

Comment: @Somos I think this is a reasonable question. I think that the OP is right that the vast majority of the time we only study an axiom system $A$ **after** having first some intuition for and interest in its class of models (or a subset thereof). Whether it's a good fit for MSE is a separate question of course (I'm not sure which way I fall on that) ...

Comment: To the OP, note that theories themselves are mathematical objects. So we can sometimes care about a particular theory $T$ not because of a preexisting interest in (some of) its models but rather because of its behavior *within the class of all theories*. For example, a counterexample to Vaught's conjecture would not necessarily be a particularly natural theory in any good sense but would be extremely interesting mathematically.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Absolutely understood - but as an answer to the question not really that satisfactory because it's a bit self-referential in a way since the "preconceived notion" already is the formalism.That people working in logic, model theory and related fields come up with (counter-) examples for their field feels like the "normal" way of how math develops.

Comment: Answer to Q1 is no. To Q2 is yes.